# SAS Token Key not generating

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I've spent the day trying to deploy some VM's in Azure from a template storage account.

I use `Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount` to set the storage account and then assign a variable to `$token = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken`

I get the error message:

> `AuthenticationFailed`  Server failed to
>   authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
>   is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:3408956-0001-00ea-4cd1-2135c2000000
>   Time:2017-08-12T21:27:54.6479108Z 
>    Signature did not match. String to sign
>   used was r 2017-08-12T22:26:51Z /blob/homeworktest/blob 2016-05-31

The powershell error message is

```
 Message=Unable to download deployment 
content from 'https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/blob/azuredeploy.json'
```

When I get the variable from $token, it displays the key which i then use with the URI to access the json file via a browser which displays the message above.

The whole code I'm using is below

```
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "ResGp" -Name "Storageaccount"
$token2 = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name "json" -Permission r -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(60.0)
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -name Demo -ResourceGroupName ResGp `
-TemplateFile "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/blob/azuredeploy.json" `
-TemplateParameterFile "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/blob/azuredeploy.parameters.json" -verbose
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, or is my whole approach flawed?

Any help\guidance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw there are 2 issues which cause your problem.

1. From your code, you are generating a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for an Azure storage container named "**json**", however the blobs which you want to download for your resource group deployment are under a different container than the container which you are generating the SAS token for.
2. Both your template and template parameters links does not have the container SAS token appended with, which means you don't have the permission to access them.

The solution for your problem:

1. Update the container name in your blob links
2. Append the Container SAS token to both your blob links

---

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -name Demo -ResourceGroupName ResGp `
-TemplateFile ("https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/json/azuredeploy.json" + $token2) `
-TemplateParameterFile ("https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/json/azuredeploy.parameters.json" + $token2) -verbose
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help, that worked a treat. Just one more quick question if I may, generating this SAS token provides access to the container for the time specified in the "expiry time" field. Does this mean when anther three or four ppl are using the same code the SAS token generated is still valid for the full duration until the expiry time? Also does this have an impact on the SAS keys (Key1 and Key2) Hope that makes sense and thanks again for your help :)